# Why does upgrading jquery from 1.7.2 to 1.8.3 result in unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[data-toggle-description-length]='toggle'
```

and none of my other js works.

but when I go back to 1.7.2 everything works ok.

The js itself has:

```
$("a[data-toggle-description-length]='toggle'").click(function(event){
 Linker.updateUi(event);
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$("a[data-toggle-description-length='toggle']")`..? Not sure why it was working in 1.7.2 in the first place.

Comment: I'm not even sure what that selector is, shouldn't the = be inside the brackets?

Comment: Wow 3 quick downvotes.  Wasn't my fault it used to work!

Comment: Good point @MichaelDurrant, no downvote from me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it previously worked due to a bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
$("a[data-toggle-description-length='toggle']")
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

The fact that your version works in 1.7.2 is most likely a bug.

Comment: Good catch +!, turned out three other files shared this bug (and effectively broke with the upgrade) as well!